# Compare time range string with select list time range

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

A user must select a start time and an end time, and I would like to compare this time range with a select list on the same page and select the options automatically that match the range of the times the user has inputed via regex if poss, or Jquery.

I was thinking converting the times to seconds and matching the ranges that way?  Not sure if possible.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

```
<label>Start Time</label>
<input type="text">10:00AM</input>

<label>End Time</label>
<input type="text">2:00PM</input>

<select>
<option>10:00AM to 3:00PM</option>
<option>10:30AM to 2:00PM</option>
<option>2:00PM to 6:00PM</option>
<option>6:00PM to 9:00PM</option>
<option>9:00PM to 11:00PM</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It definitely *is* possible.

Comment: Research the Javascript date object and try something

Comment: what about googeling "jquery compare time ranges" then try something and come back if you need help cause it is not woring

Comment: excellento - good to know its possible!  I am using moment.js to format the times, and thought https://github.com/gf3/moment-range this would make it easy.  Not sure will invesitgate further.

Comment: @tenub have you got a link or something that you could point me in the direction of?  THanks

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible to make sure the use enters a valid input using regex.

Here is a regular expression that can be used for matching strings like `2:00PM`:

```
/\d{1,2}:\d{2}(AM|PM|)/i
```

… Assuming there are no spaces.

For putting the entered value in a specific time range, you will have to write a separate script.